# Account BirthDate is one day off (Java to Salesforce API)

Tags: java, person-accounts

When I'm inserting a date from my Java code to the Salesforce it shows one day off in Salesforce. Example my Java date is 24. January 2000, and Salesforce say it is 24., February 2000.

Java:

```
Date dob = DateUtils.fromXMLGregorianCalendar(customer.getDateOfBirth());
personalAccount.setBirthDate(dob);
```

Java Test output:

```
birthDate = {Date@3147} Sun Feb 24 00:00:00 CET 1985
```

Later in my program (before I save the account):

```
account.setPersonBirthdate(DateUtils.toCalendar(salesforceAccount.getBirthDate()));
```

In Salesforce:

> Birthdate 23.02.1985

So I read somewhere that Salesforce uses GMT, but I am here giving it CET, that should be the same as GMT?

Answer (score 1):

CET is not GMT. CET is  [UTC +1](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cet) time. So you need to adjust it to GMT time before sending to SF.